# Do common passwords in TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt volumes compromise security?

Tags: encryption, passwords, truecrypt, veracrypt

I didn't find an answer in the documentation of VeraCrypt:

Does creating multiple volumes with the same password (each created individually, not just copies) compromise security (putting aside the obvious fact that if the adversary gets the password for one of the volumes, she/he could unencrypt all of them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the master encryption key is randomly generated for each volume and the header key which protects it is generated from the password with 512 bits salt, so there will be no cross-talk as there is a lot of randomness. ([Source](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Header%20Key%20Derivation))

But as you said, having different password will limit the impact in case one is disclosed by accident or force.

Comment: Is VeraCrypt not vulnerable to rainbow tables or brute forcing?

Comment: Well, bruteforcing is a thing, with all offline attacks with memorizable secrets it depends on the complexity of the password and parameters used for the strengthening. I think the defaults have been a bit weak in the past. With PIM it got a bit better, it does not yet use a slow PRF like Argon2 (used by LUKS). https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Header%20Key%20Derivation.html As for rainbow tables, the very long salt helps here a lot.